# Extract matching word and it value from all files in a directory in Unix without creating script

Tags: awk, grep

Sample file1:

```
person1|-param name=v_name -param uid=ab_cd -param email=v_name -param address=v_add -param phone=v_phone ....||
person1|-param name=v_name -param uid=de.fg -param email=v_name -param address=v_add -param phone=v_phone ..||
```

Sample file2:

```
person1|-param name=v_name -param email=v_name -param address=v_add -param -param u_id=1234 phone=v_phone ....
person1|-param name=v_name -param email=v_name -param address=v_add -param -param u_id=3456 phone=v_phone ....
```

desired output:

```
file1 uid=ab_cd
file1 uid=de.fg
file2 u_id=1234
file2 u_id=1234
```

Basically, I need to look inside all the ~200 file(*.txt) for word uid or u_id and extract the value it has after = . param are also not in same sequence in all files.

Can't create script since it in production folder so should be able to run in command line only. I tried using grep and awk but couldn't get anywhere. Anyone up for the challenge?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Thank you! That works. Who do I handle line where 1) uid=ab_cd|donot_need_this. so I need to end at |. 2) Is there a way to only print if uid value has some special character else ignore. For e.g.  if uid=ab_c*d then print that value else pass ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *desired output* (close anyway):

```
$ grep -o "u_\?id=[^ ]\+" file*
```

Output:

```
file1:uid=ab_cd
file1:uid=de.fg
file2:u_id=1234
file2:u_id=3456
```

or if you want to *extract the value it has after = . param*:

```
$ grep -Po "((?<=uid=)|(?<=u_id=))[^ ]+" file*
```

Output:

```
file1:ab_cd
file1:de.fg
file2:1234
file2:3456
```

The latter requires grep with PCRE due to lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for thist task following way, let `file1.txt` content be

```
person1|-param name=v_name -param uid=ab_cd -param email=v_name -param address=v_add -param phone=v_phone ....||
person1|-param name=v_name -param uid=de.fg -param email=v_name -param address=v_add -param phone=v_phone ..||
```

and `file2.txt` content be

```
person1|-param name=v_name -param email=v_name -param address=v_add -param -param u_id=1234 phone=v_phone ....
person1|-param name=v_name -param email=v_name -param address=v_add -param -param u_id=3456 phone=v_phone ....
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[[:space:]]"}/^u_?id/{print FILENAME, $0}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

output

```
file1.txt uid=ab_cd
file1.txt uid=de.fg
file2.txt u_id=1234
file2.txt u_id=3456
```

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that row separator (`RS`) is whitespace character so each key-value pair will be treated as single row, then for every row starting with (`^`) `u` followed by 0 or 1 (`?`) underscores (`_`) followed by `id` I `print` current `FILENAME` and that row (`$0`). If you want know more about features I used read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*